# Navbar Position Fixed disabling All Elements inside it

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have an issue that I have taken enough time and and researched enough but not found a solution to it. In the project aside, [https://github.com/dennismoha/React_Admin_template/tree/issue_branch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wv941.png), Am improving on an already created Admin dashboard made using bootstrap but now am doing it in react.
The issue is, on the normal html, the sidebar functions well and everything is well responsive and clickable but when it comes to react all the elements inside the sidebar gets **disabled**.The links also don't work. Nothing is **clickable** at all. I have gone through the code and I have realized, in the `assets/libs/css/style.css` which is the custom css for the pages, on 1627 with vscode. The '`.nav-left-sidebar`' class which is responsible for its position, on removing the "`position:fixed`" makes the buttons clickable although other page responsiveness is lost and adding it brings an issue.  I have personally established this to be the issue. I've tried researching why `position:fixed` behaves this way in react to no avail and I've tried changing to `float:left / right` and both have the same outcome. So am really requesting on what could be the issue.

**code**
**Line: 1627 css**

```
.nav-left-sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    width: 264px;
    height: 100%;
    top: 60px;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 28px 0px rgba(82, 63, 105, 0.13);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 28px 0px rgba(82, 63, 105, 0.13);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
```

snippet sample of the sidebar.

```
   <div className="nav-left-sidebar sidebar-dark">
          <div className="menu-list">
            <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
              <a className="d-xl-none d-lg-none" href="/#">
                Dashboard
              </a>
              <button
                className="navbar-toggler"
                type="button"
                data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target="#navbarNav"
                aria-controls="navbarNav"
                aria-expanded="false"
                aria-label="Toggle navigation"
              >
                <span className="navbar-toggler-icon" />
              </button>

              <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <ul className="navbar-nav flex-column">
                  <li className="nav-divider"> Menu</li>
                  <li className="nav-item ">
                    <a
                      className="nav-link active"
                      href="/#"
                      data-toggle="collapse"
                      aria-expanded="false"
                      data-target="#submenu-1"
                      aria-controls="submenu-1"
                    >
                      <i className="fa fa-fw fa-user-circle" />
                      Dashboard <span className="badge badge-success">6</span>
                    </a>
                    <div id="submenu-1" className="collapse submenu" style={{}}>
                      <ul className="nav flex-column">
                        <li className="nav-item">
                          <a
                            className="nav-link"
                            href="#"
                            data-toggle="collapse"
                            aria-expanded="false"
                            data-target="#submenu-1-2"
                            aria-controls="submenu-1-2"
                          >
                            Students
                          </a>
                          <div
                            id="submenu-1-2"
                            className="collapse submenu"
                            style={{}}
                          >
                            <ul className="nav flex-column">
                              <li className="nav-item">
                                <a className="nav-link" href="index.html">
                                  E Commerce Dashboard
                                </a>
                              </li>
                              <li className="nav-item">
                                <a
                                  className="nav-link"
                                  href="ecommerce-product.html"
                                >
                                  Product List
                                </a>
                              </li>
                              <li className="nav-item">
                                <a
                                  className="nav-link"
                                  href="ecommerce-product-single.html"
                                >
                                  Product Single
                                </a>
                              </li>
                              <li className="nav-item">
                                <a
                                  className="nav-link"
                                  href="ecommerce-product-checkout.html"
                                >
                                  Product Checkout
                                </a>
                              </li>
                            </ul>
                          </div>
                        </li>
                 
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                
               
             
                </ul>
              </div>
            </nav>
          </div>
        </div>
```

**Screenshot sample of my file structure**

[!file structure[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wv941.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wv941.png)

**Screenshot sample of my Header.js that contains the navbar, includes the Sidebar and other children properties**

[!how sidebar is loaded[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mepDe.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mepDe.png)

**browser outcome of the loaded file**
[!browser view[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pokxD.png)][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pokxD.png)

NB: I have two months in react so I might have made a problem that could be the issue to this and I can't figure it out well.

Comment: Please ad yout code

Comment: here is a git repo of it. https://github.com/dennismoha/React_Admin_template/tree/issue_branch. I thought the issue would be much more clearer when run on local that's why I shared the github link. But let me add, the code .

Answer (score 1):

I solved this. I realized there was a special way needed to add jquery libraries to react and I was doing it the wrong way by adding it in the public folder.